# Finding Directory Name in other directory with PHP

Tags: php, directory, dirname

I have a file which name is load.php near index.php in root folder. So i only have two files in root. I like clear works like most.

Today i needed to define directories in one file name is define.php. But it is not in root, i've added it to settings folder in root folder.

So my files:

- index.php (requires load.php)
- load.php (requires settings/define.php)
- settings (includes define.php)

Now i don't know how to get root folders name?

`__DIR__` in define.php gives me .../home/settings folder but i want to get root or another folders name. So what is the way?

Comment: You mean you want to find out the root directory from inside `settings/define.php`?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? If you're trying to get to a file in the root directory, the ".." operator should do the job.

Comment: Yes i mean finding root directory name from settings/define.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out the "root" directory from inside `settings/define.php`, this should be sufficient:

```
$root = realpath(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..');
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/ZjS4W)**.

Note: the linked example uses `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__` because the latter is only available on PHP >= 5.3, but is functionally equivalent.

Comment: You can also `dirname(__DIR__)` to go up one level if you are using this inside `/sub/file.php` and want the root level.

Comment: Thanks for this. But this finds up folder only. What if i want to find 'root directory' in another file. (file located anotherfolder/anotherfolder...)

Comment: I mean is there any function to find 'root directory name/way' in any folder.

Comment: @Benjamin: There's no way to do that in one step. You could do it by going up looking for a specific file, but it's better to have a configuration setting in some file that stores the root dir. Practically all PHP apps do it this way.